# How to add badges to a source list?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, rubymotion, macruby

I just wanted to know how to to implement badges like in the mail app from osx to my application without using PxSourceList : http://grab.by/nJ66

My app is developed with rubymotion for os x.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found this link for you http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=35064 May be it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know they are not available "out of the box"... PXSourceList has the best implementation of badges I have seen. Either use PXSourceList or look at the source code for it and be inspired to how it should be done.